# pipe readable stream to 2 writable streams

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't find a concise answer for a straightforward question. Hopefully this will be it.

I simply want to do this:

```
let myReadableStream = ...some readable stream...;
let myFileStream = ...some writable file stream...;

myReadableStream.pipe(process.stdout).pipe(myFileStream);
```

This doesn't work as writable streams can't be piped along.

This sort of works:

```
let myReadableStream = ...some readable stream...;
let myFileStream = ...some writable file stream...;

myReadableStream.pipe(process.stdout);
myReadableStream.pipe(myFileStream);
```

But won't this cause problems if the readable pipe fills up with data quickly before the second `myReadableStream.pipe(myFileStream)` is reached?

What's the canonical way to do this with pipes?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand node.js streams, they don't start flowing immediately on calling the `pipe()` function, work is deferred into you return control to the [event loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/).    So no, nothing will happen between the two `pipe()` calls.

I know this seems counter-intuitive to people (like me) coming from an environment based on multiple application threads.  But multiple threads is **not** the JavaScript model of concurrency.   Asynchronous JavaScript execution is instead based on the a simpler-to-manage EventLoop model, where asynch callback handling only occurs other application code is idle.  The big plus of this is that there is no need for locks, which are sometimes difficult to get right in a threaded-execution model.